# Plot derivative at correct time using influxdb/grafana

Tags: grafana, influxdb

I’m tracking my energy usage, amongst which a heat meter measuring usage in Joule. I want to calculate the heating power (in Watt), which works well with the `DERIVATIVE()` function.

The problem is that the derivative is returned on the latter of two timestamps describing the data, which when combined with the staircase plot of Grafana shows the derivative for the next time delta instead of the current.

How can I:

1. Make Influxdb show the derivative on the first timestamp of the data? (Or alternatively: shift timestamps of a query?)
2. Make Grafana plot staircase graphs extending the value left instead of right?

**Graphical example**

[image: Heat meter power calculated using Influxdb derivative() and shown with Grafana staircase line plot, where power is shown on wrong range]

**Textual example**

The following heat meter readings in influxdb

```
08:00,    0 Joule
09:00, 3600 Joule
19:00, 7200 Joule
```

will give

```
09:00, 1.0 Watt (which refers to 08:00-09:00)
18:00, 0.1 Watt (which refers to 09:00-18:00)
```

which Grafana (as staircase) will plot as

```
08:00-09:00, Null (should be 1.0)
09:00-18:00, 1.0  (should be 0.1)
18:00-,      0.1  (should be Null)
```

Answer (score 3):

I solved my own problem by interpolating the data using `GROUP BY()` and `fill(linear)` before calculating the derivative.

Create sample data

```
insert testenergy val=0     1565503200
insert testenergy val=3600  1565506800
insert testenergy val=7200  1565510400
insert testenergy val=10800 1565514000
insert testenergy val=14400 1565550000
insert testenergy val=18000 1565557200
```

yields

```
SELECT last("val") as energy FROM "testenergy" WHERE $timeFilter GROUP BY time($__interval) fill(null)

time                 energy
----                 ------
2019-08-11T06:00:00Z 0
2019-08-11T07:00:00Z 3600
2019-08-11T08:00:00Z 7200
2019-08-11T09:00:00Z 10800
2019-08-11T19:00:00Z 14400
2019-08-11T21:00:00Z 18000
```

`DERIVATIVE()` query that does not work:

```
SELECT derivative(last("val"), 1s) as power_wrong FROM "testenergy" WHERE $timeFilter GROUP BY time($__interval) fill(null)
```

The problem is that InfluxDB calculates the derivative of (t<sub>n</sub>, t<sub>n+1</sub>) at time t<sub>n+1</sub>, which Grafana using staircase plot then displays from (t<sub>n+1</sub>, t<sub>n+2</sub>):

```
time                 power_wrong
----                 -----------
2019-08-11T07:00:00Z 1
2019-08-11T08:00:00Z 1
2019-08-11T09:00:00Z 1
2019-08-11T19:00:00Z 0.1
2019-08-11T21:00:00Z 0.5
```

A solution is to interpolate the data in InfluxDB before calculating the derivative:

```
SELECT derivative(mean("val"), 1s) as power_fix FROM "testenergy" WHERE $timeFilter GROUP BY time($__interval) fill(linear)
```

yields

```
time                 power_fix
----                 ---------
2019-08-11T07:00:00Z 1
2019-08-11T08:00:00Z 1
2019-08-11T09:00:00Z 1
2019-08-11T10:00:00Z 0.1
2019-08-11T11:00:00Z 0.1
2019-08-11T12:00:00Z 0.1
2019-08-11T13:00:00Z 0.1
2019-08-11T14:00:00Z 0.1
2019-08-11T15:00:00Z 0.1
2019-08-11T16:00:00Z 0.1
2019-08-11T17:00:00Z 0.1
2019-08-11T18:00:00Z 0.1
2019-08-11T19:00:00Z 0.1
2019-08-11T20:00:00Z 0.5
2019-08-11T21:00:00Z 0.5
```

[image: Calculating derivative at any time point for irregularly spaced data points in influxdb and grafana]